# How to move SQL Data to Elastic Search Backup?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, elasticsearch

Long story short I'm really getting annoyed with the time I Have to spend, I'm assisting some in making an OSINT Service similar to Dehashed, HIBP and Snusbase. All the data we have is in MySQL Databases and I need to strip the data, Remove duplicates and push them to an ESB format. Since the damn documentation on how to do this is non-existent I'd figure I'd ask here.

I Don't know if perhaps using a python script to export tables to CSV than to JSON or what would make this task easier. I'd also like to say our data exists in the public domain, We've worked closely with victims to patch their systems, issue password resets and etc. This data is to be used ethically & will be restricted to vetted researchers, Governments, Law Enforcement and etc only. We're currently larger than the top 3 services making us the largest holder of data globally with around 200 TBs of Info and still collecting.

To finish the question: Is there a way to pull data from a MySQL Database and move it to an ESB with ease using a python3 script or through the program itself? I'm about to pull my hair out due to deadlines.

I've tried numerous methods of researching the topic without success, Tried to write a python3 script and got errors and have had 0 success with researching. My End Goal is to strip the MySQL (.SQL) files of the data that is needed & Port to a Elastic Search Backup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is way too broad and you are leaving out a lot of important details. Please have a look at [ask]. You should focus your question on a specific aspect (e.g. the problems you encountered in your Python approach) and add all the information needed (e.g. error messages, example data, minimal code to reproduce). Otherwise it is very hard to help you and very unlikely that someone will try.

Comment: do you mean Elasticsearch or another product called Elastic Search Backup? Or by Elastic Search Backup you mean an Elasticsearch snapshot? your goal is to have a search engine filled with data previously stored in SQL, or having a backup?